# Unable to scrape information from website using IMPORTHTML

Tags: web-scraping

I'm attempting to copy the information from a website directly into my Google Sheets for some analysis. Below is the HTML element from the said [website](https://vriskoapostasi.gr/el/%CE%B4%CE%B9%CE%B1%CE%B4%CF%81%CE%BF%CE%BC%CE%AE/%CE%91%CE%B8%CE%AE%CE%BD%CE%B1/%CE%92%CF%8C%CE%BB%CE%BF%CF%82).

```
<div><span id="diodia" style="display: inline-block;">Διόδια<span style="color:red;">*</span>: <strong>19.35€</strong> </span><span id="showHideTolls" style="display: inline-block;"><span id="tollsVehicle"><select id="selectSth" style="background: url(https://vriskoapostasi.gr/images/car.png) left no-repeat;width:45px;-webkit-appearance: menulist"><option value="0" selected="selected"></option><option value="1">Αυτοκίνητο</option><option value="2">Δίκυκλο</option>
<option value="3">Αυτοκινούμενο υψ&gt;2.7μ μηκ&gt;5μ</option><option value="4">Λεωφορείο θέσεις&gt;39</option>
<option value="5">Φορτηγό 2 άξονες</option><option value="6">Φορτηγό 3 άξονες</option>
<option value="7">Φορτηγό αξ&gt;=4</option>
</select></span><span id="messageTolls"></span><span>  <input type="checkbox" id="isTollSelected"></span></span></div>
```

What I want to get is the 19.35€ price located in the div above.
I use IMPORTHTML as follows:

```
=IFERROR(IMPORTHTML(A1, "//*[@id='diodia']/strong"), 0) # Where A1 holds the website link
```

But every time I get 0 because the content is empty. Why is that happening? Is there any workaround that I'm missing?

Thanks you in advance.

Comment: You will not be able to retrieve infromations since it is done by javascript on your side and not on server side: `jQuery('#diodia').html('Διόδια<span style="color:red;">*</span>: <strong>'+Math.round(tollPrice2*100)/100+'€ ('+Math.round((tollPrice2-diaforaBridgeRioFerry)*100)/100+'€)</strong> ');`

Comment: @MikeSteelson ok. bummer.